# Gettin all rows of table a that match table b

Tags: mysql

I have two tables containing peoples data, first name, last name etc.

The first table contains the data I want to select if it matches the stuff from the second table. The problem is the first table might have only an initial for the first name.

I have tried variations of the following query but I am missing something obviously. I don't mind if "J Bloggs" and "Joe Bloggs" from table 1 both match "Joe Bloggs" from table 2 that's fine.

```
SELECT t1.* ,  LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1) AS firstChar 
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.surname = t2.LAST_NAME
AND t1.firstname  = t2.FIRST_NAME
OR t1.firstname  = t2.firstChar
GROUP BY t1.surname
```

Comment: When mixing `AND` and `OR`, you will need parentheses. Try `AND (ti.firstname = t2.FIRST_NAME OR ti.firstname = t2.firstChar)`

Comment: Without a good primary key getting an perfect match is probably impossible.

Comment: @eabraham The tables come from two different databases, how can I set up a good primary key? I have just been asked to find the matches as we know table 1 has correct data and there's 100000+ rows.

Comment: You have a data integrity problem.  Take the example of John Smith and J. Smith. Both will be equivalent.

Comment: Yeah but I am sent an excel sheet from external source, not a lot I can do about that. I am only trying to narrow down the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `()` around your second `WHERE` condition as in:

```
SELECT t1.* ,  LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1) AS firstChar 
FROM t1, t2
WHERE 
  t1.surname = t2.LAST_NAME
  AND (t1.firstname  = t2.FIRST_NAME OR t1.firstname  = LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1)
ORDER BY t1.surname
```

However, the implicit join syntax is discouraged and deprecated. Instead, use

```
SELECT t1.* ,  LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1) AS firstChar 
FROM 
  t1 JOIN t2 
    ON t1.surname = t2.LAST_NAME
      AND (t1.firstname  = t2.FIRST_NAME OR t1.firstname  = LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1)
ORDER BY t1.surname
```

Since your condition is that the last name *must* match, and the first name must either match fully or match the first character, the first name conditions have to be grouped inside `()`.

I have also replaced your `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY`, since you are not performing any group aggregate functions (`SUM(), COUNT(), AVG()`).  MySQL doesn't permit aliases in the `WHERE` clause, so I have replaced `t2.firstChar` with `LEFT(t2.firstChar, 1)` as well.

Finally, you may find a need to convert the case of all the names with `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` on both sides of the join to be sure it matches where casing may be inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the parenthesis I was missing, I moved the "LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1)" up in to the select as a last ditch attempt!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need parentheses in your `WHERE` clause. Secondly, I don't think you will get anything with `t2.firstChar` unless you actually have a column in table t2 named 'firstChar'. Specifying that in your `SELECT` doesn't make it an actual row in the table. Instead, I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM
    t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON
        t1.surname = t2.LAST_NAME
        AND (
            t1.firstname = t2.FIRST_NAME
            OR t1.firstname = LEFT(t2.FIRST_NAME, 1)
        )
```